no limit in family link for Google play
All application from chids device have in Family link the possibility to set up time restrictions. Why it's not the case of Google play?
The child can browse through the application without time limits?
Or is there some way to restrict it for access? I don't mean to limit application sold/available on the platform, but the access entirely.
Thanks
I checked child device applications in Family link and probably Google play is the only which can't be limited (it's not available between apps)

Yep, this is a huge oversight!

Same problem here. Kids spend hours to just browse apps in G-Play. Outside the global time limit for usage.

I have the root cause - System applications on Android are running "always" and that's why they can't be limited based on time. Also other tools for parental control can't help .
